# How do I sort articles in category blog using a custom field value?

Tags: overrides, template-override, custom-field, sorting

I have created a custom field `date` and added content to the articles of a category.

How can I now sort the articles in the category blog overview by this field?

What should a blog.php and blog_item.php override look like?

Comment: You are not the only one who wants to know how to do this. [How to sort articles based on date in field](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=960641&sid=4494360d5d78c339f9a657c4788761ab) and this looks relevant: [Adding custom date and sort by expiry date](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=825918#p3104685)  It would be good to see this community offer an modern/professionsl solution for this reasonable task.  Ideally, this would be done at the sql level, not by using php's sorting functions.

Answer (score 0):

A BIG shout-out for Akeeba's Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos who has solved this issue. Have a look at his [sortbyfield plugin](https://github.com/nikosdion/sortbyfield)